Me da error al usar prisma db push
estoy creando un proyecto con nextjs, prisma y mongodb pero a la hora de subir los modelos a mongo me sale este error y no se por que es

he echo comprobaciones con la base de datos y no me dan fallo pero es hacer el prisma db push y me sale el error. Dejo por aquí el schema.prisma:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id       String       @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name     String
  password String
  role     String
  ext      Int
  email    String       @unique
  exps     Proceeding[]
}

model Proceeding {
  id         String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  nExp       Int
  name       String
  type       String
  assessment String
  exhibit    String
  createdexp DateTime
  lastupdate DateTime
  userId     String   @db.ObjectId
  lastuser   User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  documents Document[]
}

model Document {
  id         String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  nDoc  Int
  nExp  Int
  name String
  tipo String
  entrance DateTime
  exit DateTime
  proceedId String @db.ObjectId
  proceeding Proceeding @relation(fields: [proceedId], references: [id])
}


Ya esta resuelto era que se le había ido la ip de mongo Atlas y tuve que volver a generársela
